# How to include value from php file into jQuery and place it into span element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I get the variable in php file: like

```
$segmentData = $loadData['segment'];
echo $segmentData;
```

How can I use this value to insert/ append to span element in jQuery?!?!

I tried to place it in span element created in php file, and than extract via ID with jQuery, but didnt work.

I assume there must be better solution to this.
**EDIT:**

I am using it with ajax call with WP. I got in callback function requested data, but now I want to display that data in div or span on the fronted. 
So far, I have made span

```
<span id="segment"> <?php echo $segmentData ;?></span>
```

and in js on click get value of id "segment", and than append, but I dont wanna to make html element in php file, and this one that I tried didnt retrieve me value

Please ask me if you need more info

Comment: What JavaScript code are you trying to use? What is a possible value in `$segmentData`, and what is your expected result?

Comment: This question is very broad.  Are you using AJAX to get the data or on initial page load?

Comment: What file is `$segmentData` in? What file do you want to print the sementdata in? Please provide mode code/examples/explanations!

Comment: string , it will retrieve from db the name of segment and that is it. like "bread"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is this:

```
<?php
     $segmentData = $loadData['segment'];
?>
...
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var str = "<?= echo $segmentData ?>";
</script>
```

If you're using AJAX you can do it like this (especially if you want to load a php variable from another file)

**get-data.php**

```
<?php
   $segmentData = $loadData['segment'];
   echo $segmentData;
?>
```

**index.php (or whatever the actual page is named like)**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'get-data.php',
  success: function(data){
    $('#idOfYourSpan').text(data.response);
  },
  error: function(e, d, l){
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

There is a longer, more in-depth answer here: [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: Sidenote: `<?= echo`? `<?=` which is identical to `<? echo` therefore it should read either as `<?php echo $segmentData ?>` or `<?= $segmentData ?>` - From the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this with Jquery:

```
$('#idOfYourSpan').text('<?php echo $segmentData; ?>');
```

Your file must have '*.php' as an extension

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
var val = <?php echo  $segmentData;?>
 $('span').text(val);
</script>
```

Comment: i need in separate file, how to call $segmentData

Comment: what you need in separate file? can you plz explain in detail?

Comment: the js and php file separate, I am doing in WP plugin, where I want all things separated. I know how to append, but I dont know how to get the value from $segmentData in jQuery, which I get in php file

Comment: create page echo $segmentData in it. $('span').load('create.php');